# How cna I implement a priority queue for edges in a graph?

Tags: c#, graph, priority-queue, implementation

I want to implement my own Priority Queue in C# using the naive approach. I need to use PQ for edges in a graph to implement Prims algorithm. Here is what I've done so far:

```
public class Edge
        {
            private int v;         // one vertex
            private int w;         // the other vertex
            private int weight;    // edge weight

            public Edge(int v0, int w0, int weight0)
              {
                  v = v0;
                  w = w0;
                  weight = weight0;
              }

           public Edge()
            {
                v = 0;
                w = 0;
                weight = 0;
            } 

            public int get_weight()
            {
                return weight;
            }

            public int either()
            {
                return v;
            }

            public int the_other(int vertex)
            {
                if (vertex == v) return w;
                else return v;
            }

            public int compareTo(Edge that)
            {
                if (this.get_weight() < that.get_weight()) return -1;
                if (this.get_weight() < that.get_weight()) return 1;
                else return 0;
            }

            public string to_str()
            {
                string s = v.ToString() + " " + weight.ToString() + " " + w.ToString() + '\n';
                return s;
            }
        }

 public class MyPriorityQueue_Edge
        {
            private List<Edge> q = new List<Edge>();
            int size;
            public MyPriorityQueue_Edge() 
            {
                size = 0;
            }

            public void insert(Edge e)
            {
                q.Add(e);
                size++;
            }

            Edge Min()
            {
                int min_weight = 1000;
                Edge min_edge = new Edge();
                foreach(Edge e in q)
                    if(e.get_weight()< min_weight)
                        min_edge = e;
                return min_edge;
            }

            public Edge delmin()
            {
                Edge e  = q.Min();
                q.Remove(e);
                size--;
                return e;
            }

          public bool is_empty()
            {
                if (size == 0) return true;
                else return false;
            }
        }
```

When I compile it the compiler points to this line:

```
Edge e  = q.Min();
```

And says that I did not work on the exception "System.Argument.Exception". How can I fix this?

Comment: Your Edge class does not implement IComparable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN [`Enumerable.Min<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352408%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If type TSource implements `IComparable<T>`, this method uses that implementation to compare values. Otherwise, if type TSource implements `IComparable`, that implementation is used to compare values.

You need to implement IComparable interface in your Edge class.

`public class Edge : IComparable`

Then add a CompareTo() method. Something like

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Edge)
    {
        Edge other = (Edge)obj;
        return this.compareTo(other); // you already implemented this in your Edge class
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```